# Java MongoDB Filter records query results erroneous data

Tags: java, mongodb, swing

I've been doing some MongoDB coding following their tutorial [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/). I have made a form with a combobox to get a certain record item and clicking a button to show all similar records. while it works fine, the results are far from accurate.

Here's my Mongo Document Structure;

```
// collection: Records
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f46f75835301421ee36111"),
    "Asset Type" : "Furniture",
    "Room Number" : "01",
    "Barcode" : "55454",
    "Item Description" : "Des",
    "Acqusition Date" : "10/28/2017",
    "Value" : "2100"
}
```

I'm filtering by Room Number. Here's my code;

```
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                comboSelected = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println(comboSelected);
            }
        });

    JButton btnG = new JButton("Get Data");
    btnG.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
              String str2 = comboSelected;
              System.out.println(str2);
              // Below Method is to get all room data on selected room
              Block<Document> roomBlock = new Block<Document>() {
                     @Override
                     public void apply(final Document document) {
                         System.out.println(document.toJson());
                         //textBlock.setText(document.toJson());
                         //str1 = new String (document.toJson());
                     }
                };

                collection.find(gt("Room Number", str2)).forEach(roomBlock);
        }
});
```

How ever for example if i were to select Room 1, I will get records that are not relevant.

What is it i'm doing wrong? can anyone help? (TIA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a wrong filter "gt"

```
collection.find(gt("Room Number", str2)).forEach(roomBlock);
```

After going through MongoDB's query [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) I found i need to use "eq" to filter my results. so if you're having the same problem try this.

```
collection.find(eq("Room Number", str2)).forEach(roomBlock);
```